# Einstein Index Notation to prove identity

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, tensors

> By using index notations, prove the following identity $$(\vec u\cdot \vec v)^2+|\vec u\times\vec v|^2=|\vec u|^2|\vec v|^2$$ where $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ are vectors in $\Bbb R^3$.

I tried to write $$u_iv_iu_jv_j+|(u_kv_l\varepsilon_{klm}e_m)|^2$$ But I don't know how to expand the second term.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use the [Levi-Civita symbol product formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Three_dimensions_2)

$$ \sum_{i=1}^3 \varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{imn}~=~\delta_{jm} \delta_{kn}-\delta_{jn} \delta_{km} .$$

In [Einstein notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) we don't write the summation $\sum_{i=1}^3$ explicitly because it is implicitly implied by the repeated index $i$.